# Add two matrices

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a problem "Index was outside the bounds of the array." and can't understand where is a problem

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
Console.WriteLine("If you want add elemenets of matrix, it should 
have same number of rows and columns\n");
Console.Write("Enter number of rows FOR FIRST NATRIX: ");
int rows = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter number of columns FOR FIRST NATRIX: ");
int columns = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");

int[,] matrix = new int[rows, columns];

Random random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        matrix[i, j] = random.Next(111);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        Console.Write(matrix[i, j] + "\t");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.Write("Enter number of rows FOR SECOND NATRIX: ");
rows = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter number of columns FOR SECOND NATRIX: ");
columns = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");

int[,] matrix1 = new int[rows, columns];

Random random1 = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        matrix[i, j] = random1.Next(111);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        Console.Write(matrix[i, j] + "\t");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

double[,] Sum = new double[rows, columns];

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        Sum[i, j] = matrix[i, j] + matrix1[i, j];
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; i < columns; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {Sum[i, j]}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

}

Comment: Look at matrix1 and see where it is used - think about using functions to refactor the code and make it more readable. Then look at indexes and your last summation of two matrices.

Comment: if only there was a debugger where you can step through your code and inspect values, live would be so much easier - oh wait there is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022

Comment: you do realize your bottom code isn’t using the variable `matrix1` but `matrix`? why should this line work `Sum[i, j] = matrix[i, j] + matrix1[i, j];` when first and second matrix have different rows/colums?

Comment: Your last `for` statement says `for (int j = 0; i < columns; j++)` but you probably mean `j < columns`.

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't repeat yourself, *extract methods*; we want to create, sum and print matrixes:

```
private static int[,] CreateRandomMatrix(int rows, int columns, int scale) {
  int[,] matrix = new int[rows, columns];

  for (int r = 0; r < matrix.GetLength(0); ++r)
    for (int c = 0; c < matrix.GetLength(1); ++c)
      matrix[r, c] = Random.Shared.Next(scale);

  return matrix;
}

private static double[,] SumMatrix(int[,] left, int[,] right) {
  double[,] result = new double[
    Math.Min(left.GetLength(0), right.GetLength(0)), 
    Math.Min(left.GetLength(1), right.GetLength(1))];

  for (int r = 0; r < result.GetLength(0); ++r)
    for (int c = 0; c < result.GetLength(1); ++c)
      result = (double) left[r, c] + right[r, c];

  return result;
}

private static void PrintMatrix<T>(T[,] matrix) {
  for (int r = 0; r < matrix.GetLength(0); ++r) {
    if (r > 0) Console.WriteLine();

    for (int c = 0; c < matrix.GetLength(1); ++c) {
      if (c > 0) Console.Write("\t");

      Console.Write(matrix[r, c]);
    }
  } 
}
```

And then play as simple as

```
...
int[,] matrix = CreateRandomMatrix(rows, columns, 111);

PrintMatrix(matrix);

...

int[,] matrix1 = CreateRandomMatrix(rows, columns, 111);

PrintMatrix(matrix1);

var Sum = SumMatrix(matrix, matrix1);

PrintMatrix(Sum);
```